# How to write this same code and get same data in eloquent relationship ... laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

How to write this same code and get same data in eloquent relationship

```
 public function index(){
    
    $data = DB::table('categories')
    ->join('subcategories', 'categories.id', 'subcategories.cat_id')
    ->select('categories.*', 'subcategories.*')->paginate(5);
    return view ('admin.subcategory.index', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `hasMany` relationship between Category and Subcategory.

**Category** model

```
class Category extends Model
{
     public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory','cat_id','id');
    }
}
```

Now you can call `with('subcategories')`

```
Category::with('subcategories')->paginate(5)
```